# CPU is changing fan speed to maximum

Tags: cpu, upgrade, fan

I have `Intel Pentium 4, 2800 MHz (21 x 133)` 478 socket processor and `Hewlett-Packard HP d530 SFF` motherboard, and a noisy CPU fan. In BIOS fan speed on idle is set `2/4` (50C-65C) because my motherboard will overheat (68C) if I set it to `1`.

I wanted to upgrade motherboard with better CPU, and so have got this other [CPU](http://www.cpu-world.com/sspec/SL/SL79K.html), it's `14 x 200`, so it's better ofcourse. [Here are some images](http://www.google.com/search?hl=lv&biw=1024&bih=639&q=SL79K%20%28Intel%20Pentium%204%202.8%20GHz%29&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=544l544l0l1071l1l1l0l0l0l0l371l371l3-1l1l0&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi).

I didn't know what socket it was, but after I took off CPU fan, I realized that it was same.
No problems were while I was installing it.

I started the PC and fan was spinning normal 2 seconds (like with first CPU), but after those few seconds fan was spinning at maximum.

I didn't reboot, because I wanted to check temperatures. After Windows 7 started and installed this CPU (didn't restart system). I checked CPU temp, but logically it was at 25C, the system temperature value was 89C (very high, and Windows lagged very much, maybe because I needed to restart the system to affect on processor drive). I used HWMonitor.

So I went to BIOS to change `Fan speed on ILDE` setting but no effect. Also there was a new setting called `allow CPUID maximum value 3` (or something like that) it was set to `disabled`. I changed it to enable and fan started to lower speed. After speed wans`t so horribly noisy, I just saved settings (F10) and restarted. But I was disappointed because fan was spinning at maximum.

Now I have old configuration (old CPU and BIOS settings) and nothing seems to be different.

So Im sure that it was CPU problem.

- Since CPU was used in other PC, I will check that PC.
- My fan is blowing to PSU. If I rotate it, I will to need to change wire from `CPU_FAN` to `CASE_FAN` because it wont reach `CPU_FAN`.
- My PC doesn't have a case fan, so my BIOS is showing `ERROR 512 Case fan not detected`

Maybe I should disable SMBUS?

**Edit**
The new CPU was damaged.

Comment: Was there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: The CPUID setting is for older operating systems which can't properly recognize new CPUs and then won't boot. It has nothing to do at all with heat management. Next did you try cleaning and lubricating the CPU fan? Or maybe even replacing it? The motherboards should definitely be able to survive the full speed of the fan. If it can't for some reason, try getting a converter which will allow you to power the fan from a molex port in the power supply and avoid the motherboard. Also can you post pictures of what your computer looks inside?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are using XP (or newer) as your operating system, there is no need to touch/change CPUID and I would disable it again.

All this being said, I doubt you will see much gain in speed with the newer processor - certainly nothing major and you would be better of saving the money or buying a second hand Core 2 machine.

However, as you have bought it and are on a budget, I would take a guess (as you did not specify) that you did not use any new thermal compound. I am making this guess as I have seen these symptoms quite a few times. The fan usually kicks in at an average speed and the moment that the thermal sensors kick in, it spins it up higher.

Pentium 4 era machines were notorious for their heat and if your fan has lasted this long, well done! I have had a few clients with newer Prescott based CPUs that gave up about 2 years ago - so, you have done well but it may be time to upgrade the fan.

Answer (score 0):

Robrok what is the possibility that the fan control was speeding up because there is not sufficent contact with the heatsync?
that the cpu IS hot, and that the thermal control on the fan is setting it up to a higher speed.
that the heat sinc would need to have proper thermal goop , and be seated fully.

That the "system" which is the "chipset" on my board, is not cooling for the same or other reasons, and that could also cause the motherboard software to raise the speed of the fan (which would be odd for it to raise the cpu fan for the system)

that you have speedfan or another speed controller involved in software in the system?
disabling the SMbus, or that other buss that they communicate to the motherboard to mess with the motherboard operations MIGHT give you clues to any other software "drivers" that are installed to effect theses items.

looking IN the device manager for the various drivers that would be doing those kinds of communications.

checking any thermal management software that was applied by the hardware utilities

I donno, but there is a list to think aboud